# Is the AMP lab done next February?

Tags: apache-spark

First, I'm not sure where to post this, so feel free to close if it doesn't belong here.

Is there a way to track whether Berkeley's AMP lab will indeed shutdown next year?

From their [about site](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/about/):

> The AMPLab is a five-year collaborative effort at UC Berkeley

and it was started in February 2011.

So, I was curious if this was a hard date, or if it will be extended (or has already been extended?)

Comment: Good idea will be to ask this on dev@spark.apache.org (dev mailing list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaying an answer from AMP director Mike Franklin:

> One year into the lab we got a 5 yr Expeditions in Computing Award as
>   part of the White House Big Data initiative in 2012, so we extend the
>   lab for a year.   We intend to start winding it down at the end of
>   2016, while supporting existing projects and students who will be
>   finishing up.   The AMPLab faculty are starting discussions this
>   summer about what research challenges we'd like to tackle next, and
>   how best to organize to do so.
>
> An interesting thing to note is that the Spark project started at
>   about this point in the AMPLab predecessor project (RADLab) so we have
>   a track record of being able to make these transitions.

Comment: Can't get much more official than that :). Thanks!